# Is there a more succinct way of performing the same task below? Rounding down to nearest 1 or 5mod6

Tags: dart, rounding

```
var n = 27;

void main() {

  while  (n>=5)

    if ( (n) % 3==0 && (n) % 2==0 ){
      print(n-1);
      break;
    }
    else if ( (n) % 3==0 && (n) % 2!=0 ){
      print(n-2);
      break;
    }
    else if ((n) % 3!=0 && (n) % 2==0){
      print((n/6).floor()*6 +(1));
      break;
    }
    else { n=n+1;}

}
```

I was looking for a way to have an input reduced to the nearest 1 or 5mod6 (for n>=5) and came up with the code above in Dart (project is in flutter). Does anyone have any better way of doing the same thing?

The result (rounded down input) will then be passed to another function.

For the current n value of 27 the console will print 25... try other values 24 maps to 23, 23 to itself, 22,21,20 to 19, 19 to itself, 18 to 17, 17 to itself, 16,15,14 to 13.....and I hope you get the idea.

Comment: In Python I'd write this as `n - min((n+1)%6, (n+5)%6)`. I don't know dart, but presumably it's a simple translation?

Comment: Thank you, this may be useful for someone in the future, and that might also be me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the loop by finding the next lower multiple of 6 and then adding 1 or 5.  The code ends up being shorter, and I think it expresses your intent much more clearly than code involving `% 3` and `% 2`.

```dart
int lowerMultiple(int n, int multipleOf) =>
    ((n - 1) / multipleOf).floor() * multipleOf;

void main() {
  var n = 27;
  var m = lowerMultiple(n, 6);
  print((n - m) >= 5 ? (m + 5) : (m + 1));
}
```

The above code should work for integers less than 5 as well, including non-positive ones.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What if `n == m` or `n + 3 == m`? The question says "reduce to the _nearest_ 1 or 5 mod 6", but those values are equally distant from  `n-1`/`n+1` and `n+1`/`n+5`. The examples suggests that it really should round *down* to the next one, so `n` a multiple of 6 should round down to `n - 1`. You seem to be rounding `n == m` up to `n + 1`.

Comment: @lrn: There's a sneaky `n - 1` in the definition of `lowerMultiple`. I think that means that this answer does the right thing when `n` is a multiple of `6`. (For example, if `n = 24`, then `m = 18`, so we end up with `23`.)

Comment: Got it. That *was* sneaky (and why we need documentation in real-world examples!)